# How dropdown menu moves on right side in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I got a problem when using native dropdown menu of wordpress, my menu drops the elements on the left side, but I want to move its on the right side.
Here is the css code

```
div#navigation 
  { 
   float: left; position: 
   relative; left: 50%; 
   margin-bottom: 35px; 
  }
select.mobile_menu { display: none; }
div#navigation ul { 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0; 
   float: left; 
   position: relative; 
   left: -50%; 
 }
 div#navigation ul li { 
    float: left; 
    position: relative; 
    margin: 0px; 
    margin-left: 50px; 
    padding-top: 12px; 
    padding-bottom: 10px; 
    font-family: 'Vollkorn', 'Times New Roman', serif; 
 }
div#navigation ul li:first-child { margin-left: 0px; }
div#navigation ul li ul.sub-menu { 
     display: none; 
     float: none; 
     position: absolute; 
     top: 50px; 
     z-index: 10000; 
     background: #F8F8F8; 
     border: 1px solid #CCC; 
     border-bottom: 0px; 
 }
div#navigation ul li:hover ul.sub-menu { display: block; }
div#navigation ul li ul.sub-menu li { 
     position: relative; 
     float: none; 
     margin: 0px; 
     border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC; 
     font-size: 14px; 
 }
div#navigation ul li ul.sub-menu li a { 
    display: block; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 23px; 
    line-height: 23px; 
    text-align: center; }
div#navigation ul li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu { 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: -202px; 
 }
div#navigation ul li ul.sub-menu li:hover ul.sub-menu { 
    display: block; 
    top: -1px;}
div#navigation ul li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu { display: none; }
div#navigation ul li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu li:hover ul.sub-menu { 
    display: block; 
    top: -1px;
 }
```

This is my own web and the problem as the
[photo](http://mai.decorners.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Untitled.png)
.What should I change in the css ?

Comment: What about trying something?

Comment: I did but css isn't my professional part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved , only change the left argument -200px to 200px 
`div#navigation ul li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-menu { display: none; position: absolute; left:200px;`